# Php simple login script via session

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm new to php and I'm having issues with creating a login scripts. In the first part of code, it can find the correct id belonging to the person logging in and sets in correctly in the $_SESSION['id']. Then the script redirects back to the index but here I get an error saying the id isn't set in the session.

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\gym\v1\content\body\panel.php on line 11

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    session_regenerate_id(); //Regenerate session ID to prevent session fixation attacks
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $member['id'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: ../index.php?page=2");
    exit();
}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?page=1");
    exit();
}
?>
```

---

```
session_start();
echo 'session id:' . $_SESSION['id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['id']) == '')) {
    echo 'error not session id set';
    exit();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$mail = $member['emails'];

echo '<h1>Welcome!'. $mail  . ' </h1>';
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think the `$member` has no `id` element

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: In your login script, you never call `session_start()` prior to setting `$_SESSION['id']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your login script, you never call `session_start()` prior to setting `$_SESSION['id']`.

Also, It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @thecatontheflat thanks for that. I copy/pasted from my comment & it left the links out.